# Re-arranging pivot column and value using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to rearrange the pivot table in the way that base on this input data, the revenue_month will be treated as a column, keeping all other indexes, whereas the columns:revenue__net_eur and accrual__net_eur will be the values.

```
data = {
    'cust_id': [1, 1, 1, 1],
    'cust_name': ['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company A', 'Company A'],
    'doc_num': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'created_at': ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-15', '2023-04-01'],
    'payment_method': ['Credit Card', 'PayPal', 'Credit Card', 'PayPal'],
    'status': ['Paid', 'Paid', 'Disputed', 'Paid'],
    'currency': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR'],
    'net_amount': [1000, 1500, 2000, 2500],
    'vat_amount': [200, 300, 400, 500],
    'gross_amount': [1200, 1800, 2400, 3000],
    'revenue_month': ['2023-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-02-28'],
    'revenue__net_eur': [800, 1200, 1600, 2000],
    'accrual__net_eur': [1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]
}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Final output:
[image]

The indexes are not as important, I am interested in pivoting the `revenue_month` with the two values : `revenue__net_eur, accrual__net_eur`.

What I've tried so far:

```
# create a pivot table with 'revenue_month' column labels
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['revenue__net_eur', 'accrual__net_eur'], 
                             index=['customer_id', 'doc_num'], 
                             columns=['revenue_month'], 
                             aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

# swap the order of the column index levels
pivot_table.columns = pivot_table.columns.swaplevel(1, 0)
pivot_table
```

which only results in:
[image]
The Python code is wrong because `revenue__net_eur` should come as a column before `accrual__net_eur` for each particular month, where the order of revenue_month is ascending.
*see the final output table*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# swap the order of the column index levels
pivot_table.columns = pivot_table.columns.swaplevel(1, 0)

# create MultiIndex with expecting order
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['revenue_month'].unique(),
                                 ['revenue__net_eur','accrual__net_eur']])

# change order of MultiIndex in columns
pivot_table = pivot_table.reindex(mux, axis=1)

print (pivot_table)
                      2023-01-31                        2023-02-28  \
                revenue__net_eur accrual__net_eur revenue__net_eur   
cust_id doc_num                                                      
1       101                  800             1000                0   
        102                 1200             1500                0   
        103                    0                0             1600   
        104                    0                0             2000   

                                  
                accrual__net_eur  
cust_id doc_num                   
1       101                    0  
        102                    0  
        103                 2000  
        104                 2500
```

EDIT: If first level has strings instead datetimes in format `DD/MM/YYYY` and cannot change format in final data:

```
dates= (df['revenue_month'].drop_duplicates()
          .sort_values(key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True)))
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, 
                                  ['revenue__net_eur','accrual__net_eur']])
pivot_table = pivot_table.reindex(mux, axis=1)
```

Another idea:

```
dates = (df.assign(new_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['revenue_month'], dayfirst=True))
           .sort_values('new_dates')['revenue_month'].unique())
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates,['revenue__net_eur','accrual__net_eur']])
pivot_table = pivot_table.reindex(mux, axis=1)
```

Another idea is convert column to datetimes before pivot - in ouput is default format of datetimes - `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
#convert to datetimes before pivoting
df['revenue_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['revenue_month'], dayfirst=True)

pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['revenue__net_eur', 'accrual__net_eur'], 
                             index=['cust_id', 'doc_num'], 
                             columns=['revenue_month'], 
                             aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

# swap the order of the column index levels
pivot_table.columns = pivot_table.columns.swaplevel(1, 0)

# change order of sorted datetimes
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['revenue_month'].sort_values().unique(), 
                                  ['revenue__net_eur','accrual__net_eur']])
pivot_table = pivot_table.reindex(mux, axis=1)
```

Comment: thx @jezrael , in my view, the revenue_month is not in ascending order. column c&d are 2023-04-30, column e&f 2023-01-31, and so on. 
I tried adapting the order by:
# create MultiIndex with expecting order
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['revenue_month'].unique(),
                                 ['revenue__net_eur','accrual__net_eur']]).sort_values(ascending=True)

but now accrual__net_eur comes before revenue__net_eur

Comment: @Luc - Can you check EDIT part in my answer?